# Do distribution-preserving maps preserve statistical independence?

Tags: probability, independence

Consider a random vector $\mathbf{X}=[X_1,...,X_d] \in \mathbb{R}^d$, which is dimension-wise statistically independent (i.e. $p(\mathbf{X})=p(X_1)...p(X_d)$).

Assume a function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a distribution-preserving map (i.e. $\Pr(\mathbf{X} \le \mathbf{x})=\Pr(f(\mathbf{X}) \le \mathbf{x})$).

Is $\tilde{\mathbf{X}}=f(\mathbf{X})$ also dimension-wise statistically independent (i.e. $p(\tilde{\mathbf{X}})=p(\tilde{X}_1)...p(\tilde{X}_d)$) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [definition of independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#For_real_valued_random_variables) is
$$P(\mathbf{X} \le \mathbf{x}) = \prod_{i=1}^d P(X_i \le x_i), \qquad \text{for any $x_1,\ldots, x_d$}.$$
(Note that this definition makes sense without any assumptions on whether the $X_i$ are discrete or continuous random variables.)

Using this definition, you can show that $P(\mathbf{X} \le \mathbf{x})=P(f(\mathbf{X}) \le \mathbf{x})$ is enough to conclude $f(\mathbf{X})$ has independent components.